# Plotting a line graph with vertical and horizontale segments

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following table

```
>Anna
    from     to      values
    5        10       34
   10       14       45
   14       23       46
   23       34       54
```

So I want to make a line graph which on the x axis will have the from and to value and on the y the results.

In more details, I need to have a dot on the value 5 (from) then a line to a dot 10 (to) at height 34 (y axis) and then the line goes from the dot 10 to to 14 at 45 value of y axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `segments` draws segments!

```
> mydata
  from to values
1    5 10     34
2   10 14     45
3   14 23     46
4   23 34     54

plot(NA,xlim=c(0,40),ylim=c(0,60))
points(values~from,data=mydata)
points(values~to,data=mydata)
segments(mydata$from,mydata$values,mydata$to,mydata$values)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: thank you very much!!!!! However is there a way to draw lines also in the intermediate empty spaces? for example in the value 10 I want a vertical line to connect the two orizontal lines (results 34 and 45)

Comment: Aha, then I would use type='s'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `type="s"` option to plot step functions. 
(If you need the dots, you can add them with `points` afterwards.)

```
# Sample data
n <- 10
instants <- c(0, cumsum(rexp(n)))
d <- data.frame( 
  from = instants[1:n],
  to = instants[-1],
  value = cumsum(rnorm(n))
)

plot( c(d$from[1], d$to), c(d$value, d$value[n]), type="s" )
```